# discord.py same string assigned to json dictionary twice

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot that uses JSON, and I'm following a tutorial about making a discord bot leveling system [(Here is the link)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKkrCHnun0M)

I'm not trying to make a leveling system, but I want my bot to be able to add a list of users to the file. This is the code I'm using.

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open('Users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

        await update_data(users, member)

        with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    with open('Users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

        update_data(users, message.author)

        with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)

async def update_data(users, user):
    if not user.id in users:
        users[user.id] = {}
```

The problem is, when I type "test" it adds my user ID to the JSON file, and when I type "test" again, it adds it again, but it only does it twice. I'm confused by this, is there a solution?

EDIT: This is what the JSON file looks like before I run the bot:

```
{

}
```

And this is what it looks like after (This isn't my actual user ID, it's just a fake user ID because I don't want to use my actual one.)

```
{"392755610348320683": {}, "392755610348320683": {}}
#This is the JSON file after posting a discord message twice
```

Comment: Can you add what you json file looks like in your question?

Comment: I'm not pretty sure `if not user.id in users:` then `users[user.id] = {}` do in your code? Why remove data instead append when not found?

Comment: @Kouheng I don't think they're removing data. `user.id` is confirmed to not be in `users` in this case. So, when a user joins, if their ID doesn't already exists in `users`, they add it.

Comment: Why do you load two seperate JSON files?

Comment: @LercDsgn Oh, I see. but append an Index with empty dataSet is still kind of weird for me. Normally my json file will add some initial data instead of adding an empty set.

Comment: @ColemanEthington Good point, I should have included the JSON file. I added it now.

Comment: @Kouheng since dictinoaries in python have the same operator for adding new keys and assigning values to them and assigning existing keys new values, I think this code won't be programmatically. It's always good to see a template of what properties an item would have, though, I agree.

Comment: @mahdude17 does the json miss a curly bracket every add or is it only on the first add? 
so is the json like this when run another time, i.e added a third id -> `{{{"id": {}, "id": {}, "id":{}}` OR `{{"id":{}, "id":{}, "id":{}}`

Comment: @mahdude17 (sorry for twice mention) regarding above comment, if former is the case, the pointer seems to shift one each time the code is run. try the `fileobject.seek` method. Since you're not adding but overwriting the json, go to the beginning by passing 0 as the single argument.

Comment: @LercDsgn no, I just accidentally added a curly bracket. The dataset actually looks like: {"392755610348320683": {}, "392755610348320683": {}}

Comment: @mahdude17 then, what's the problem? Can you explain more? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @LercDsgn I want to make it so that every time someone types a message it adds them to the JSON dictionary. It's supposed to, when it gets a message, look at the user of that message and check if that user is already in the dictionary or not If it's not in the dictionary, it adds the ID, but if it is in the dictionary it doesn't. Right now, though, it is adding the ID to the dictionary twice. It's supposed to add the ID one time when the user types the first message, but it adds it twice after the user sends two messages. It does not send it thrice. This is my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I didn't figure out why this happened, but it's always good to state the solution to a problem if you solve it yourself. If I change user.id to str(user.id), it doesn't assign the string twice.